# Meteor doesn't import external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, import

I have a javascript file stored in **client/template/missionPage.js** from where I would like to import a javascript file stored in **client/lib/scripts/textRotate.js** I have tried all kind of import paths but none of them worked. e.g import txt from './lib/scripts/textRotate.js';
All o them give the same error: Uncaught error cannot find module './lib/scripts/textRotate.js'. Can anybody help?

Comment: The path should be `../lib/scripts/textRotate.js`

Comment: It worked ! But can you tell me please why do I have to put ".." two dots? @ChrisG

Comment: Two dots means "up a level", and you need to leave the `template` folder first. A single dot refers to the current directory.